# How to fix Spanish-Style Milkfish that became Too Salty

Tags: fish, salt, olive-oil, spanish-cuisine

My wife made spanish-style milkfish, when I tasted it during the night it was alright, but when I tasted it next day for breakfast it has become too salty! I searched for recipes and saw that you're supposed to rinse the fish in running water after soaking it in brine for 1 hour but my wife says the recipe she found did not say that the fish should be rinsed. Is there any way to still fix this? The fish is already too soft to be rinsed and Im not sure vinegar or lemon juice would get through the olive oil. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I'd suggest making it over.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We did not want to waste the ingredients so my wife researched a bit more and was able to remedy the saltiness by soaking the fish in hot water and fresh milk solution for an hour, drained it, and put back the sauce in, then added a bit more chili pepper.

Comment: You should answer your own question then!

Comment: Hey, @sneftel: another reminder not to close a new member's first question without explaining why in the comments!

Comment: Also tagging @rumtscho: ^^^

Comment: @FuzzyChef Thank you for reminding me. The proportion of first-time users who come back is so small that I am indeed not consequent enough with explanations, especially for duplicates. As for the successful desalting, I am somewhat surprised that the other question doesn't have an answer recommending soaking, since it applies to a very large class of oversaltable foods. This is an excellent opportunity for someone to write up an answer there, where it will be seen by more eyeballs, instead of having it here, where it will be discovered only by people making this specific type of fish.

Comment: Ok how do I post the answer? It was my wife who found it she just described it to me.

Comment: @KaousFaustDesIncarnus: per Rumtscho above, post an answer on the other question, in the more general form of "you can soak it in milk".